# WordPress : Error 500 server apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

Every so often (3-5 times per day) my website with wordpress, the error 500 is shown, that the error log file and .htaccess.

Error log

```
[Wed Jun 22 15:44:08 2016] [error] [client 200.232.198.193] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "POST" at REQUEST_METHOD. [file "/opt/mod_security/hg_rules.conf"] [line "148"] [id "900405"] [msg "xmlrpc POST logging"] [hostname "mysite.com"] [uri "/xmlrpc.php"] [unique_id "V2sGqGynpUQAAfVkEcAAAAA1"]
[Wed Jun 22 15:44:08 2016] [error] [client 200.232.198.193] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 406 (phase 1). Operator EQ matched 0 at REQUEST_HEADERS. [file "/opt/mod_security/hg_rules.conf"] [line "206"] [id "900331"] [msg "Joomla Com_Content SQL Injection POST"] [hostname "mysite.com"] [uri "/xmlrpc.php"] [unique_id "V2sGqGynpUQAAfVkEcAAAAA1"]
[Wed Jun 22 15:45:27 2016] [error] [client 107.167.108.81] Failed loading /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, referer: m.facebook.com/l.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmysite.com%2Fasi-funciona-crash-bandicoot-en-skylanders%2F&h=qAQEA1o9T&s=1&enc=AZPY63wsEzGY-uswftS7o2D68MwDewef6cFT9eJAu3Ezo3UeVsTRF2KoE_b64G7ctf_XdeIWTALoY79RYDaWw7iX
[Wed Jun 22 15:45:28 2016] [error] [client 186.36.158.160] Failed loading /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, referer: mysiteo.com/asi-funciona-crash-bandicoot-en-skylanders
[Wed Jun 22 15:45:46 2016] [error] [client 200.73.66.2] Failed loading /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, referer: mysite.com/2-buenos-humble-bundles-para-hacerte-de-hartos-juegos
[Wed Jun 22 15:46:20 2016] [error] [client 201.219.233.58] Failed loading /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: /usr/php/54/usr/lib64/php/modules/ZendGuardLoader.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, referer: mysite.com/monoterapia-pilotwings-64-y-super-mario-64/?utm_medium=nt&utm_source=nt&utm_campaign=snow%20boots&utm_content=durable%20%snow%boots
```

Verified!

.htacces :

```
RewriteEngine on
<FilesMatch ".(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
   Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800"
   Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
  RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml 
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

Comment: The .htaccess file seems irrelevant here, but what is the question?  Issues with mod_security, the Zend Guard error, both?

Comment: the question is, how can I fix the error? D:

Comment: There are 2 different unrelated errors.  So it's probably the Zend Guard error causing the 500's.  Are any of your PHP files encoded with Zend Guard?  Those lines from the error log are probably not the relevant lines.

Comment: my wordpress site with php but not if used Zend Guard, the Error log sent me the hosting